# Get the column type by the input PHP

Tags: php, database, column-types

So I have a question. I am currently looking at [RedBeanPHP](http://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php) and I like how they can create tables, in development, on the fly and then freeze the schema for production.

I am looking to do something simmilar. Now what Im curious about is if PHP community has built anything where I can do:

`$someClass->someFunction('string'); // Gives me back string as the column type.`

Or:

`$someClass->someFunction(99.0); // Gives me back double`

and so on.

Does anything like this exist? I have tried searching and found nothing but you never know. Is there anything built into PHP to do this? I know theres various functions to see if bool, if string and so on, but that doesn't cover all the database column types.

**Any help is appreciated**

Comment: [gettype()](http://www.php.net/gettype) exists. This however does not return "database column types", just PHP types. Object-Relational-Mapping is no easy task and usually requires some kind of developer configuration regarding columns (eg. configs / annotations).

Comment: Well I was trying to figure out how red bean managed to do it with out configuration and just allowing you to assign properties to a bean (that part i figured out) and then the value of those properties would then create the column and set the type. @ccKep

Comment: you can `var_dump($var);` to see if it is a string, float, int, etc...

Answer (score -1):

Execute your variable inside `var_dump($varhere);` and it will display what it is. You can do a simple query to ASSOC Array, and then run a for each loop with an var_dump($var); and it will print what it is...

```
$a = array(1, 2, array("a", "b", "c"));
var_dump($a);
```

will out put the following

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
  }
}
```

Same with

```
<?php

$b = 3.1;
$c = true;
var_dump($b, $c);

?>
```

will dump out

```
float(3.1)
bool(true)
```

I recommend you look at [PHP Manual - var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)